# Group Using SQL and Keeping Initial Records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I am using GROUP BY and HAVING to select a number of consumers that qualify for a program in our company. We're basing this on the balance that consumer has from any number of accounts that they are associated with (One To Many).

Here is an example of the code:

```
select   consumerid, 
         sum(balanceonaccts) bal,
         group_concat(accountid) accts
from     accounts
join     consumer 
on       consumer.consumerid = accounts.consumerid 
group by consumerid
having   bal > 300"
```

This gives me information on who meets the qualifications on the consumer level, however, the only way I've been able to identify the accounts that combined to meet the balance is to use group_concat().

I was wondering if there was a method to identify those consumers who's accounts combined meet the balance criteria, and then somehow move the output down to the account level.

When I attempt to:

```
group by accountid
```

It excludes consumers who's accounts alone wouldn't meet the balance required but summed together would pass the threshold.

Comment: Could you post table schema? We need to know which table owns each field. Or at least prefix every field with its table name.

Comment: Sure thing:  consumer.consumerid , accounts.balanceonacct, accounts.accountid, accounts.consumerid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the group of `consumerid` values that meet the criteria, so you can use the existing query as a derived table and just join again to `accounts` to get the accounts:

```
select
    a.consumerid,
    a.accountid,
    a.balanceonaccts,
    ba.bal
from
    accounts a
    inner join (
        select
            ac.consumerid, 
            sum(ac.balanceonaccts) bal
        from
            accounts ac
            inner join consumer co on
                co.consumerid = ac.consumerid 
        group by
            ac.consumerid
        having
            bal > 300
    ) ba on ba.consumerid = a.consumerid
order by
    a.consumerid,
    a.accountid
```

Comment: Thank you! It was as simple as doing this to get the consumer ID's then re applying the criteria after the join on the account level. I was able to match the accounts to the consumer balance perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select a.*
from accounts a join
     (select a.consumerid, sum(balanceonaccts) as bal
      from accounts a
      group by a.consumerid
      having bal > 300
     ) aa
     on a.consumerid = aa.consumerid;
```

I dont' think you need the `consumers` table at all, unless there are some specific fields you want from that table.

Comment: I did want some specifics from that consumer table, but the logic you posted here was exactly what I needed to solve the problem. Thanks for the help!